# Валидация формы на JS(jQuery). Нужно сделать проверку. Если Tel или Email ввели, тогда форма отправляет

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

У меня есть форма:

```
<form class="form-box" action="">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя *">
 <input id="form-phone" class="form-phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" minlength="10" maxlength="10" >
 <input id="form-mail" class="form-mail" name="form-mail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"  >      
</form>
```

Нужно сделать:
Если ввели телефон или email- форма отправляет. В другом случае нужно, чтобы ввели что-то из этих параментов (телефон или мейл).

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте атрибут `required`  и не нужно заморачиваться с **jQuery**

```html
<form class="form-box" action="">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя *">
     <input id="form-phone" class="form-phone" required name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" minlength="10" maxlength="10" >
     <input id="form-mail" class="form-mail" required name="form-mail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"  > 
     
     <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Второй вариант с **jQuery**

```js
$(function ($) {
    const $inputs = $('input[name=phone],input[name=form-mail]');
    $inputs.on('input', function () {
        $inputs.not(this).prop('required', !$(this).val().length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-box" method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя *">
 <input id="form-phone" class="form-phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" minlength="10" maxlength="10"  required >
 <input id="form-mail" class="form-mail" name="form-mail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"  required >    
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Andrew если ответ решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку рядом.